# Native Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, native

This might be better suited as a Super User question, but since it's programming related, I put it here:

Is there any version of the Eclipse IDE available that runs as a native Windows executable, instead of as a Java program that's merely *started* by a .exe file?

(I'm guessing it could potentially be compiled with GCJ, so I'm wondering if anyone's already done it.)

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of such a thing and I have been involved in Eclipse development for many years. Why would you want such a thing? Surely not for performance as a modern JVM runs Java code on par with native code and faster in many case as JIT can optimize and re-optimize on the fly better than a static compiler.

Comment: I'm just asking for a Windows equivalent of [something that's already been done for Linux](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7413)...

Comment: Interesting experiment, but doesn't appear to be more than that, nor is it extensible in any way. What good is Eclipse without plugins? So what do you want this for?

Comment: Eclipse startup is Goddarn slow on Windows (due to the JRE loading); a cold start takes ~30 seconds. Even a *warm* start takes ~5 seconds, while Visual Studio 2008, for example, takes < 2. I frequently find myself opening files with Visual Studio or even Notepad++ simply because of the startup time, even though Eclipse would be better for my tasks in many cases. (This is, btw, why I also don't like VS 2010.)

Comment: It was not an experiment, but extremely powerful project. I believe the only reason for abandonment was the fact that GCJ is more/less abandoned project as well... Konstantin, native build of Eclipse is VISIBLY faster than the Java one. It is blazingly fast. PS. it is weird that someone who is "involved in Eclipse development for many years" does not know about this...

Comment: Exactly. GCJ was abandoned because there was no point to it any more. The article was written on 2004. Even by that time, JVM technology was getting close to running Java on par with native code. By 2012, it's not even a competition. No static native compiler can beat JIT compiler that continuously re-optimizes the code based on actual usage.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik not to sound like a troll, but that means either Java is garbage or Eclipse is very badly written.  Just a quick scan of Google shows how many people using Eclipse just want to speed the bloody thing up.

Comment: @JustCallMeNew if you don't want to sound like a troll, don't make comments that make you sound like one. You will find similar performance complaints about any sufficiently-complex software. See FireFox, Outlook, etc. Has nothing to do with Java vs native. Core of Eclipse is highly optimized. Plugins vary dramatically in quality and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Excelsior JET has done this with Eclipse Classic Juno as a demo for their Eclipse RCP support.
Have a look here: https://www.excelsiorjet.com/solutions/protect-eclipse-rcp-applications